# how to print a page from web browser without print window using javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript, browser

I am developing an POS application for my own shop in web. Now for that in billing section have features like select the products and print bill, this process is only two steps. However when I click print I am greeted with a print setup window which is obviously very annoying and delays things.

**Question:**

*How do I disable print setup when printing from browser?*

Comment: This is more related to Windows/Mac OS and your browser and is more suited on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

You cant print from JavaScript without user interaction - and this is a good thing: Think of a rogue website, that just prints and prints and prints, costing you lots of money for print supplies and effectively DOSing your printer.